# How differentiate between user input and setText method in TextWatcher?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm using a `RecyclerView` that contains items containing a `EditText` each one.

I add a `TextWatcher` in this EditText in the ViewHolder constructor. This text watcher call: `adapter.notifyItemChanged()`

When bind views, I do:

`edittext.setText("value");`

So text changed event is fired, but I don't want that beacuse I get

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while
>   RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling

I want that event is fired only when user changes the text manually. Is there a way to differentiate this events?

I could remove and add again the `TextWatcher` each time views are binded but I'd like find another better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting the TextWatcher in the ViewHolder constructor, you can do that while binding the view, right after the setText() call, avoiding the problem you are experiencing.

So:

```
edittext.setText("value");
edittext.setTextWatcher(new TextWatcher(..
```

This way the TextWatcher will not immediately fire an event because it didn't yet exist when the initial value was set.

Comment: Thanks. And I should remove this watcher before call `setText` to prevent the error in the next refresh. Is that correct?

Comment: @bigdestroyer I do not think that is necessary because the view will be "recreated" or redrawn when you notifyItemChanged(), but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Correct. It doesn't crash. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to attach the text watcher in the binding method, just after the editext.setText("value")